# Can threads deadlock hang whole JVM itself?

Tags: java, performance, deadlock

Is it possible that Java Virtual machine hang itself when multiple threads 
    running in  it get into a deadlock? 
    My purpose to ask this question is :
    If I know where threads can deadlock I want to put some recovery logic like timeout
    or  something and handle the situation.
    If Java Virtual machine hangs itself then it won't work.

```
Class TwoThreads{

try{
Thread threadA = new Thread();
Thread threadB = new Thread();
// some multithreaded logic goes here where deadlock possible
catch(Throwable t){
  threadA.interrupt();
  // some handler logic
  }

}
```

Comment: By definition, a deadlock won't throw an exception. It will make the deadlocked thread wait forever. If deadlock is possible, then fix the code so that it's not possible anymore.

Comment: @JB Nizet Tks. My example is wrong, but my question is basically to know if thread deadlock can hang the total JVM or will other parts of application can still keep running?

Comment: A deadlock, by definition, causes some threads to wait forever. If these deadlocked threads are the only threads of your app, then nothing will happen anymore. If there are other threads running, then they will continue running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you face with deadlock, so this means `application has designed very BAD`! the deadlock is not kinda exception, so you would manage your mutex and resources in such a way that no any deadlock will appeared.
but simply you would give a timeout to `wait()` method when a thread is going to wait for a `notify()` signal. something like this.

```
public void run(){
...
  _mutex.wait(10000);//release the lock and waits for 10 seconds
...
}
```

and about your doubt, JVM will not hang itself!